# How to check if path in xpath exists?

Tags: python, xpath

This code successfully checks if xpath if a single element exists in xpath:

```
x = root.xpath("boolean(//*[contains(local-name(), 'bar')])", namespaces=lnamespaces)
print("xx ", x)
```

But I need to check if a path like `foo/bar` is exists. I tried:

```
x = root.xpath("boolean(//*[contains(local-name(), 'foo/bar')])", namespaces=lnamespaces)
print("xx ", x)
```

However, the code above evaluates to false even if the `foo/bar` path exists.

Code:

```
from lxml import etree

mystr = """
<some>
    <foo>
        <bar>
        </bar>
    </foo>

    <baz>
    </baz>
<some>  
"""
etxml = etree.HTML(mystr)

result = etxml.xpath("boolean(//*[contains(local-name(), 'foo/bar')])")
print("result: ", result)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of xml code with both conditions you're testing for?

Comment: @JackFleeting done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but I'm afraid the only way I could get there is like this:

```
tree_struct = etree.ElementTree(etxml)
for e in etxml.iter('bar'):
   print('/foo/bar' in tree_struct.getpath(e))
```

Output:

```
True
```